# Firebase - how to retrieve post data only where the slug URL matches a key in the object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am very new to firebase and I am unable to fetch the blog port with the help of **Slug key value**. I tried out few things but all were unsuccessful.

Can anyone help me out in fetching the data please?

I want to fetch my blog post data with the help of **Sulg URL**, not behalf of key.
See the image below

I have this key value `quickly-extract-email-address-from-text`

with the help of **ID** i am getting this blog post data.

```
 const [article, setArticle] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {

    const docRef = doc(db, "BlogArticles", id);
    onSnapshot(docRef, (snapshot) => {
        setArticle({ ...snapshot.data(), id: snapshot.id });
    });

    
}, []);
```

[image]

**but i want the same data with the help of this key value `quickly-extract-email-address-from-text`**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're asking [how to execute a query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries) against Firestore. Based on that, you'll want something like this for the query:

```
const articlesRef = collection(db, "BlogArticles");

const q = query(citiesRef, where("slug", "==", "quickly-extract-email-addresses-from-text"));
onSnapshot(q, (snapshot) => {
  snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
    setArticle({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id });
  })
});
```

Keep in mind that if your database would ever contains multiple documents matching the query, this would only end up showing the last of those matches.